# VirtualBox - Mac OSX host Win7 guest - no Internet access for guest VM

Tags: windows-7, macos, virtualbox

I have a Mac running OSX 10.9.2, and I just downloaded and installed a Win7 IE9 VM in VirtualBox. My Mac uses Wi-Fi for internet access, and it's behind a proxy (it's a work machine). VirtualBox loads the VM fine, and at some point the VM can see the DNS servers of the host. But I've never been able to make the VM have internet access. I've tried all kinds of combinations of Network settings on the VM via the VirtualBox > Settings, in conjunction with Internet Sharing in OSX's System Preferences, but no luck.

Has anyone done a similar setup and made the VM successfully connect to the Internet? Thanks in advance for any inputs.

[ Update:
I was able to get internet access for the VM when the host was using my home network. When I ran the VPN software to connect to the work network, the internet access went away again.]

[ Update 2:
Okay, the problem above has been fixed, thanks to the person who answered it first.

**Now I have a further problem**:  I have a web server process running from the host (Mac), which is accessible to a browser running in the host as well, via any of the following URLs: http : // l o c a l h o s t:/ or "http:hostIPAddress:port/" .  The guest VM is unable to access this web address (with a browser running in the VM), but in a terminal/command window from the guest VM, I can ping the *hostIPAddress*.  What gives?  This is the last remaining segment of the setup I'm trying to achieve. Thanks again for further responses.  Please feel free to indicate if this problem needs to be moved to another question. ]

(Initially posted this on stackoverflow.com, but it was put on hold as off-topic by several users, and was advised to ask here instead)

Comment: What do you mean exactly that the VM can see the DNS Servers of the host?  These DNS Servers on the intranet or internet?

Comment: DNS servers on the intranet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at the network settings for the VM. If all you need is to get "out" from the VM (and neither the host, nor any other device on the network ever needs to initiate a connection to the VM), then setting the VM to "NAT" is probably the easiest way to go.

In the guest OS (Windows), obtain an IP address automatically. In the guest's browser make the same proxy settings as on the host machine.

There is no need to change any network settings on the host machine – VirtualBox will handle all network traffic for the VM. (If you use a different network setting, such as "Host only", that would be a different matter.)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this soon and update here.  In the meantime I was able to get internet access for the VM when the host was using my home network.  When I ran the VPN software to connect to the work network, the internet access went away again.

Comment: Running a VPN client is a different story again... the VPN client creates a new, virtual network interface and routes all traffic through that. VPN clients commonly block "split tunneling", i.e. being able to talk to machines in your company network and directly to machines on the Internet at the same time. In that case, all your Internet traffic would need to go through the VPN and your company's proxy server. That means you need to configure your company's proxy server in the guest while connected to the VPN.

Comment: I was able to access the internet from the VM, by following what you said (just left the mode to NAT, and set the browser proxy settings the same as the host's).  There was a confusing status of 'No Internet Access' with the LAN icon at the bottom bar of the VM, which made me think there was still no access after these settings were made.  A restart of the VM fixed that false status. Thanks!!